# Loop through files and remove part of filename

Tags: powershell

I need to remove the first 3 chars of every file in my directory. Here is my code:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\New Folder" -Filter *.txt |
foreach-object -process {rename-item -path $_.FullName -newname ($_.Remove(0,3))}
```

I do not understand why this is not working. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5):

$_ refers to the file object. Not to the file's name. I suspect that this just slipped your mind since you do refer to $_.Fullname for the -Path. Try referencing the name instead of the object when you rename it:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\New Folder" -Filter *.txt |
foreach-object -process {rename-item -path $_.FullName -newname ($_.Name.Remove(0,3))}
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem "D:\New Folder"` failed for me on a mapped network drive. `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "D:\New Folder"` worked. Same for `-path` in the `rename-item` section. Changing that to `-LiteralPath` fixed that also.